# Recreate transparent icon in Figma

Tags: color, transparency, icon, color-reproduction, figma

I am trying to recreate the below icon in Figma. I have the background color (*#F3764A*) but since each Dimond is transparent, I cannot get the actual hex color or the opacity which make recreating it really hard.

[image: Image to recreate]

I tried getting a approximate color and changing the opacity but nothing works.
Somehow, this was the best I could do but, um...

[image: My recreation try.]

Comment: And no, I cannot ask the original creator for the colors because if I don't know who it is. I found it online.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The shapes look like they are filled white, but with the opacity/alpha lowered to around 33%. The orange background is merely showing through.

I made this example below in Inkscape as I'm not a Figma user, but it should be possible in Figma too, or any vector based software.

[image]

Comment: Wow! Thanks, that looks perfect! My diamonds look wrong though, do you think you could share the dimensions and rotations with me? Thanks again!

Comment: @TalinTheDev I'm sorry, but I ddn't keep the file.  Use the original image to get the size right.